# How do i sum fields inside a column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this: Table Name: Accounting

| year | acc | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | in | 500 |
| 2018 | out | 500 |
| 2019 | in | 600 |
| 2019 | out | 800 |

I need to show up to 10-year slots with the highest value (i.e in + out). For example, in this case, 2019 is the highest, my query should show

| year | Max Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2019 | 1400 |

My current SQL code is:

```
SELECT year,acc, MAX(value) as max_value
FROM Accounting 
group by year,acc
LIMIT 10
```

How can I get the desired result?

Comment: Simply skip acc in the SELECT and GROUP BY.

Comment: "show up to 10-year slots with the highest value" I don't understand this statement

Comment: @P.Salmon I need to sum both in + out which the highest value then show the highest grouped by the year

Comment: @jarlh, it doesnt cosider out, I tried it. I need to consider both. it has to be in+out

Comment: @Strawberry it means just show the first 10 result

Comment: And do SUM() instead of MAX()... I meant.

Comment: Can I suggest editing that statement accordingly, and perhaps providing a more representative data set and corresponding desired result - and note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `SUM()` and `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT year,acc, SUM(value) as sum_value
FROM Accounting 
GROUP BY year
ORDER BY sum_value DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

If you want only ten years to be considered, you need a `WHERE` clause, for instance:

```
SELECT year, SUM(value) as sum_value
FROM Accounting 
WHERE year >= 2010
GROUP BY year
ORDER BY sum_value DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding your question, but what it appears you are attempting to complete the following steps.

1. You are trying to `SUM` by year, regardless of account type, the amount in the `value` column.
2. You are trying to show only the years with the 10 highest summed values over some specified period of time.

One way to approach this would be as follows

```
SELECT year, SUM(value) as annual_value
FROM Accounting 
GROUP BY year
ORDER BY annual_value desc
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `SUM()` not the `MAX()`, because you don't want only the highest value, but the total, and then you only have to `GROUP BY` them by year

```
SELECT year,sum(value) as max_value
FROM Accounting
group by year
LIMIT 10;
```

Here's the result:

```
+------+-----------+
| year | max_value |
+------+-----------+
| 2018 |      1000 |
| 2019 |      1400 |
+------+-----------+
```